# Automatic domain from axis limit

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using pgfplots for many plots in my report and I am having to specify `xmin`, `xmax` and domain for every axis, even though I always need the domain to be `xmin`:`xmax`.
Is there a way to set the domain to be automatically equal to the `xmin`:`xmax` from the axis?

For example, in this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-10, xmax=10,
  % domain=-10:10 %% Can I specify this automatically?
  ]
  \addplot {cos(deg(x))};
  %\addplot[domain=xmin:xmax] {cos(deg(x))};   % Or even this?
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define the xmin and xmax manually using `\def\xmin{10}` or, when once defined in the plot, you can use `domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}`

Comment: `pgfkeysvalueof` is what I am looking for, thanks! I guess it wouldn't be possible to set at `axis` level without the extra command because the variables are not yet set at that point.

Comment: Note that when the domain exceeds the xmin : xmax, it will compute points outside the axis (that are clipped).

Comment: @Excelsior, do you want to write an answer or shall we close the question as "solved in the comments"?

Comment: @StefanPinnow You can close it as "solved in the comments"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.